# How to log an entire request (headers, body, etc) for a certain url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, logging

I need to log all the requests including HTTP headers, bodies, etc to a certain url. I've tried this code:

```
def index
  global_request_logging
end

private

def global_request_logging 
    http_request_header_keys = request.headers.keys.select{|header_name| header_name.match("^HTTP.*")}
    http_request_headers = request.headers.select{|header_name, header_value| http_request_header_keys.index(header_name)}
    logger.info "Received #{request.method.inspect} to #{request.url.inspect} from #{request.remote_ip.inspect}.  Processing with headers #{http_request_headers.inspect} and params #{params.inspect}"
    begin 
      yield 
    ensure 
      logger.info "Responding with #{response.status.inspect} => #{response.body.inspect}"
    end 
  end
```

But it said `request.headers` doesn't contain a method named `keys`. Also I figure there should be an easier way or standard to do it. Preferably, not to use a gem.

Comment: The header comment does not have a keys method. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/Headers.html

There is an instance variable called `env` that is a hash containing the values. So you should be able to do `request.headers.env.keys`. To understand how the header class works, check out the source, it's pretty small: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e7b0947afdc8c9f4119d06628070667b9e7875d1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/headers.rb

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like `request.headers` returns a hash, but in fact, it returns an instance of [`Http::Headers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/Headers.html) that doesn't have a `keys` method defined.

But a `Http::Headers` responds to `env` which returns the original env hash. Therefore, the following works:

```
http_request_header_keys = request.headers.env.keys.select do |header_name| 
  header_name.match("^HTTP.*")
end
```

Or you can just iterate over all key-value-pairs and copy them into another hash:

```
http_envs = {}.tap do |envs|
  request.headers.each do |key, value|
    envs[key] = value if key.downcase.starts_with?('http')
  end
end

logger.info <<-LOG.squish
  Received     #{request.method.inspect} 
  to           #{request.url.inspect} 
  from         #{request.remote_ip.inspect}.  
  Processing 
  with headers #{http_envs.inspect} 
  and params   #{params.inspect}"
LOG
```

To wrap this up:

```
around_action :log_everything, only: :index

def index
  # ...
end

private
def log_everything
  log_headers
  yield
ensure
  log_response
end

def log_headers
  http_envs = {}.tap do |envs|
    request.headers.each do |key, value|
      envs[key] = value if key.downcase.starts_with?('http')
    end
  end

  logger.info "Received #{request.method.inspect} to #{request.url.inspect} from #{request.remote_ip.inspect}. Processing with headers #{http_envs.inspect} and params #{params.inspect}"
end

def log_response
  logger.info "Responding with #{response.status.inspect} => #{response.body.inspect}"
end
```

Comment: Well, that's a half of the solution. How about logging the body?

Comment: @jawanam : I updated my answer with an example of an `around_action`

Answer (score 7):

I'm using this to get the full headers:

```
request.headers.env.select do |k, _| 
  k.downcase.start_with?('http') ||
  k.in?(ActionDispatch::Http::Headers::CGI_VARIABLES)
end
```